# Login as Experience User with Multi-Factor Authentication Enabled

Tags: experience-cloud, multi-factor-authentication

We have been developing a Salesforce application with a Community portal.  As system admins (or regular internal users) we can easily Login To Experience As User.

We want to enable MFA for our Experience user.  In our sandbox we enabled MFA using High Assurance on the Session settings for an external profile.

However, now when we try to Login to Experience as User, as see the login page.  As soon as we disable MFA, we are able to login directly, like before.  Clearly, enabling MFA has caused this

Is there any way around this so that our internal users can login as experience users even with MFA enabled for experience users?

Comment: Are your system admins logging in as a high assurance session? From the [FAQ docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388806&type=1) if they're not in a high assurance session themselves this can interfere with the Login As functionality.

Comment: TY.  In our sandbox we do not have High Assurance enforced for internal users (or SSO enabled there).  I will see if we make that change what happens.

Comment: That did seem to fix it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the suggested fix as an answer for anyone else that encounters this issue.

Due to that fact that enabling MFA for Experience Cloud users enforces that they are operating with a High Assurance session, the internal users that are using privileged functionality such as Login As also need to be in a High Assurance session for this to work without being impacted by the MFA enablement.

This is mentioned in the [MFA FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388806&type=1) under the 'Does MFA affect the Log In As Another User option?' section.